# Why does the child runtime come up as negative?

Tags: c, fork, child-process

I did a little test to see how much longer the child process execution takes with fork() compared to the parent. However, running this program, I get the execution for child to somehow come up as negative.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    clock_t begin = clock();

    printf("Before fork\n");


    pid_t pid_return = fork();


    char* x;

    if(pid_return != 0){
        x = "Parent";
    }
    else{
        x = "Child";
    }

    clock_t end = clock();

    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin);
    printf("%s time spent: %f\n", x, time_spent);
}
```

Output:

```
Before fork
Parent time spent: 197.000000
Child time spent: -2143.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

`clock()` isn't (wall clock) runtime, it's the amount of CPU used by the current process. By using `fork()` you've presumably reset this time to 0 in the child process (because it hasn't used any CPU yet). That's why `end` is much smaller in the child and subtracting the parent's `begin` from it makes it go negative.

Comment: How does the child access other variables from the earlier code from the parent that was executed before fork(), but it cannot access the time variable?

Comment: @AdityaPokharel What time variable?

Comment: I meant clock variable (sorry!)

Comment: @AdityaPokharel OK, what clock variable?

Comment: clock_t begin = clock();

Comment: @AdityaPokharel You mean `begin`? That can be accessed just fine (as your code demonstrates). I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your answer earlier. That makes sense, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is completely legitimate, because the clock in the child process starts at a different point in time: parent's `clock` starts when the parent process is spawned, while child's `clock` starts after the `fork`.

You can demonstrate this with a simple test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Before fork\n");
    pid_t pid_return = fork();
    clock_t time = clock();
    char* x;
    if(pid_return != 0){
        x = "Parent";
    } else{
        x = "Child";
    }
    printf("%s time : %f\n", x, (double)time);
}
```

This program prints a smaller number in the `child`, because its clock is not running prior to hitting the `fork`. On my system the output is

```
Before fork
Parent time : 2684.000000
Child time : 617.000000
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks heaps!